# "group by" creating issue

Tags: sql, database, join

My query is as follows:

```
select 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate , 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGSellRate,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "'
  and INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date)"
```

In this query I have used group by sauda_date.

Its grouping it by sauda_date but grouping the values of current month first and then last month.

I want exactly opposite, It should group it by Feb, then march.

My data visualizer is as follows:

[image]

Here as we can see that it should first show values for 28 Feb 2013 then for March month values.

I have also tried Order by with following query:

```
select AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate , AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGSellRate,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword from tradefile where scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) desc
```

but it gives me following error:

```
Column 'tradefile.Sauda_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

**NOTE:** sauda date is nvarchar

What is the mistake in my query?

Should I add something more in it?

EDIT Query:

```
select 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate , 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGSellRate,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "'
  and INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) desc
```

[image]
Please guide me.

Comment: order by giving me error.

Comment: you must be placing the order by at the wrong place.

Comment: @shradha I have posted what happens with order by

Comment: use, Group by and order by. dont leave out group by, aggregate functions like SUM, AVG all need group by!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate , 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGSellRate,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "'
  and INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' 
group by sauda_date order by sauda_date asc
```

this should work!

Answer (score 1):

you can use **order by** sauda_date to make it the way you want

Comment: you have to change group by 'tradefile.Sauda_Date' in your query and order by 'tradefile.Sauda_Date'

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate , 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGSellRate,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "'
  and INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) asc
```

Comment: should i use first order by then group by ?

Comment: problem means i am getting same result.

Comment: order by asc--> will give you: january to dec. order by desc --> will give you: dec to jan. hope you have used asc.

Comment: asc gives the same result, with desc i have pasted image of the result...its giving me 28 Feb 2013 then 22 Mar 2013 , 21 mar 2013 , 20 mar 2013...and so on...plz help me.